# How to prevent TextField from disappearing in SwiftUI List?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uikit, swiftui, textfield

There's a nasty SwiftUI bug in which a `TextField` disappears if placed in a `HStack` within a `List`

```
List {
    ForEach(0...200, id: \.self) { index in
        HStack {
            Text("Text \(index)")
            TextField("Test", text: .constant("TextField \(index)"))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

https://recordit.co/X12uGct7gD

This happens when `TextField` is placed within a `HStack / VStack / ZStack / .overlay() / .background()`. It does not happen when `TextField` is the only child of `ForEach`.

I have filed a bug (FB7500885) but I'm looking for ideas from the community to work around it. Here is what I've tried so far:

- Setting an explicit `.frame()` on `TextField`
- Setting `.fixedSized()` on `TextField`
- Using a `UITextField` wrapped in a `UIViewConvertible`, with or without layout constraints

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Which Xcode version do you use? For statistics purpose.

Comment: This happens on Xcode 11.2 and 11.3, both on device and simulator.

Comment: Just hit this today. Maddening! Glad to have found your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following one:

```
  List {
      ForEach(0...200, id: \.self) { index in
          HStack {
              Text("Text \(index)")
            TextField("Test", text: .constant("TextField \(index)")).id(index)
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. Having to use `id()` still feels like there's a bug in SwiftUI, but at least this is a clean workaround.